# Yii2 loginform doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, yii2

Loginform in yii2 doesn't validate password properly. I have typed right password but it says that password is wrong.
Here is my controller

```
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\User;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup','language'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout','set-cookie','show-cookie'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending email.');
            }

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }



    /**
     * Languages.
     */
    public function actionLanguage()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['lang'])){
            Yii::$app->language = $_POST['lang'];
            $cookie = new \yii\web\Cookie([
                'name' => 'lang',
                'value' => $_POST['lang']
            ]);

            Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requests password reset.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
    {
        $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset password for email provided.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Resets password.
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function actionResetPassword($token)
    {
        try {
            $model = new ResetPasswordForm($token);
        } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->resetPassword()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New password was saved.');

            return $this->goHome();
        }

        return $this->render('resetPassword', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is my model

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

I have registration and user create pages. When I use data of registered user then all right and when I use data of created user then all is wrong.

this is `UserController` and I think the problem in `generatePasswordHash()` in `actionCreate` function of this controller

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\models\User;
use frontend\models\UserSearch;
use frontend\models\Schedule;
use frontend\models\Photo;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/**
 * UserController implements the CRUD actions for User model.
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all User models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new UserSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single User model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new User model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();
        $schedule = new Schedule();

        $pass = Yii::$app->request->post('password_hash');

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $schedule->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $schedule->save()) {
            $model->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password_hash);
            $model->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            if ($model->save()) {

                $photoList = $_FILES['files']['name'];
                foreach ($photoList as $value) {
                    $newPhoto = new Photo;
                    $newPhoto->user_id = $model->id;
                    $newPhoto->photo = $value;
                    $newPhoto->save();
                }
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'schedule' => $schedule,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionValidation()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing User model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = User::findOne($id);
        if (!$model) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user was not found.");
        }

        $schedule = Schedule::findOne($model->id);

        if (!$schedule) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Error");
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $schedule->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $isValid = $model->validate();
            $isValid = $schedule->validate() && $isValid;
            if ($isValid) {
                $model->save(false);
                $schedule->save(false);
                return $this->redirect(['user/view', 'id' => $id]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'schedule' => $schedule,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing User model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the User model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return User the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

view file

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Countries;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use kartik\time\TimePicker;
use kartik\file\FileInput;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\User */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="user-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName(), 'enableAjaxValidation' => true, 'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute('user/validation')]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'notes')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Countries::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        [
            'prompt' => 'Страна',
            'onchange' => '
                        $.post( "../states/lists?id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                        $( "select#user-state" ).html( data );
                        });'
        ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'state')->dropDownList([],
        [
            'prompt' => 'Регион',
            'onchange' => '
                        $.post( "../cities/lists?id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                        $( "select#user-city" ).html( data );
                        });'
        ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList([],[ 'prompt' => 'Город' ]); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'salary')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'hiredate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter hire date ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'=>true,
            'format'=> 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'birthday')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birthday ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'=>true,
            'format'=> 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>




    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'monday_start')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'monday_end')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'tuesday_start')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'tuesday_end')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'wednesday_start')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'wednesday_end')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'thursday_start')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'thursday_end')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'friday_start')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'friday_end')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'saturday_start')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'saturday_end')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'sunday_start')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($schedule, 'sunday_end')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 't1',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showSeconds' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            'minuteStep' => 1,
            'secondStep' => 5,
        ]
    ]); ?>



    <?= $form->field($model, 'dismission')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter dismission date ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'=>true,
            'format'=> 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <div class="cont">
      <div class="demo-gallery">
        <ul id="lightgallery">
          <li data-responsive="/bridalpro/frontend/web/uploads/dodge.jpg 375, /bridalpro/frontend/web/uploads/dodge.jpg 480, /frontend/web/uploads/dodge.jpg 800" data-src="/bridalpro/frontend/web/uploads/dodge.jpg"
          data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Classic view from Rigwood Jetty on Coniston Water an old archive shot similar to an old post but a little later on.</p>">
            <a href="">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/bridalpro/frontend/web/uploads/dodge.jpg">
              <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
                <img src="/bridalpro/frontend/web/img/zoom.png">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash gallery_delete" data-name="dodge.jpg"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" id="filer_input1" multiple="multiple">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" id="filer_input2" multiple="multiple">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: check password in DB.

Comment: Do you have User model? i.e do you have `users` table in the database and a model represent it? If yes, Do you store the password as a plain text in the database?

Comment: @sємsєм yes i have user model and user table.i store password as password hash

Comment: Well, your code seems to be the standard code generated by Yii. However, try to create user using your `users` controller and see what is going?

Comment: Can you add your login template file also in your question? and while creating a user how you are generating the password for that user?

Comment: @Manikandan S i have edited my question

Comment: @ sємsєм nothing new

Comment: @Bakhtiyar still I can't see the template file in your question. can you please double check your question?

Comment: @Manikandan S i have added my view file. i hope you mean view file

Comment: @Bakhtiyar Thanks for adding your view file. Yes I mean view file only. I hope you are assigning the password for new user inside this method-'$model->signup()'. Now check assign password process and $user->validatePassword()- methods are doing the same process. If you confused, please add those methods too.. sorry for asking again and again.

Comment: @Manikandan S i checked, assigning password and $user->validatePassword() are doing the same. I am getting password hash in database but not correct hash

Comment: @Bakhtiyar Ok. if it is not correct hash, please find out what is the problem or do add those methods also. It will help us to find out the problem

Comment: Is table user looking like this?  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `password_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `password_reset_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `auth_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

Answer (score 0):

The issue, mainly, in your `UserController`. Look at the following lines in the `actionCreate`:

```
    $pass = Yii::$app->request->post('password_hash');

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $schedule->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $schedule->save()) {
                $model->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password_hash);
.......
```

look again at the last line of the snippet:

```
$model->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password_hash);
```

It should not be like above, it should be:

```
$model->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your user model, you should add a plain text for requesting password and then hash it in your controller.

here is the example.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->created_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
            $model->setPassword($model->password);
            $model->generateAuthKey();
            $model->status = User::STATUS_ACTIVE;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->getPrimaryKey()]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

$model->password is the field you add manually in the user model.